# R: How can I filter out a specific variable value from each table in my list of tables?

Tags: r

Suppose you had a list of 200 tables each containing the variable "cyl". In the variable "cyl", there are three values ("4", "6", and "8"). In R, how could I filter out the value "4" from each of the 200 tables?

The code for the list generation is provided below.

```
output <- list()

iterations <- 200

for(i in 1:iterations){
  output[[i]] <-  mtcars <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), size = 15, replace = FALSE), ]

}
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `lapply(output, subset, cyl != 4)`

Comment: @jdobres Thanks! This is the answer. If you post this I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, if you have an operation you'd like to apply over a list of items, `lapply` is usually the right choice:

```
lapply(output, subset, cyl != 4)
```